# Sending TLS 1.2 request in Python 2.6

Tags: python, ssl, request, python-requests, python-2.6

I am stuck using Python 2.6 and I need to send a post request using TLS 1.2. Does Python 2.6's `requests` library support TLS 1.2? How do I ensure/verify that the request is made via TLS1.2 and not some other version?

A sample request is

```
r=requests.post(url,data=payload,verify=False)
```

Somewhere on the forum I came to know that we need to compile `pyOpenSSL` to support this. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 17):

The `ssl` module in Python 2.6 supports up to TLS 1.0 only.  If you do not wish to introduce additional dependencies (such as pyOpenSSL as you suggest) you will need to upgrade to Python 2.7 or 3.x to get support for newer versions of TLS.

To force a particular version of TLS in **Python 2.7.9 or later**, [construct an `SSLContext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext) with the appropriate [`PROTOCOL_*` constant](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version).  You can then use it with any API that lets you provide your own `SSLContext`.

```
import ssl
import urllib2

ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
# set other SSLContext options you might need
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
```

To use a particular protocol version *or higher* (including future versions), use `ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23` and then disable the protocol versions you do not want to use:

```
ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)

# allow TLS 1.2 and later
ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2
ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
```

As for using a custom `SSLContext` with Requests in order to force a particular protocol version, <strike>[according to the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request) there does not seem to be a way to do this</strike>, [see the following example from the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version).

Comment: Thanks @frasertweedale .How do I specify the version of TLS while sending the request ?

Comment: Updated answer with more info and `ssl` module code examples.  Unfortunately there does not seem to be a way to do this with the Requests library.

Comment: What if the server is enforcing TLS 1.2 request will it be possible with requests library in python? In my case when I captured the packet using wireshark ,what I observed was the request which was going out of client machine was TLS 1.0 but  the packets captured at server was TLS 1.2 .I am  not able to figure out that since sending a request via protocol and not via specific port ,the server and client are negotiating to communicate via TLS 1.2 .This link has says that https://luxsci.com/blog/ssl-versus-tls-whats-the-difference.html

Comment: @testedboy the article you linked is confused and uses strange terminology.  The SSL and TLS handshakes are similar; both are "by port".  "By protocol" refers to application-layer protocol upgrade mechanisms like STARTTLS.  As you have pointed out, the SSL/TLS version is negotiated during the handshake; typically the high version supported by both server and client is used.

Comment: @fraserweedale Hmm Thanks.My only concern is that on forums I came across that request library for python2.6 does not support TLS1.2 .And my client is written completely in python2.6 and uses requests library for sending request.So,if client does not have support for that how is the negotiation happening and the response server is gettting request with TLS1.2.

Comment: The requests library does support setting particular versions of ssl: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version

Answer (score 0):

If upgrading the code isn't an option, you should be able to proxy your connection using a squid server or nginx.  Here's a squid "bump" method example:

[Can I use Squid to upgrade client TLS connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398484/can-i-use-squid-to-upgrade-client-tls-connections)

Another option is to keep the proxy but rewrite the URL (http to https) and have your application send requests to http (seems odd but works if implemented right).