# SSL library on Python 2.7.10 does not contain PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2 and upgrading SSL library results in error

Tags: python-2.7

Trying to use `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` to make TLS1.2 HTTPS requests using Python 2.X.

It was suggested in this thread ([Sending TLS 1.2 request in Python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153271/sending-tls-1-2-request-in-python-2-6)) that I need to switch from Python 2.7.6 to 2.7.10, which I did, and then utilize the `ssl` library.

Unfortunately, after switching to Python 2.7.10, I was unable to access `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` (apparently I can't post images).

I'm fairly sure I'm using Python 2.7.10 because when I activate my virtual environment and call Python from the command line I see:

`Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

I thought maybe that the issue was that the `ssl` library was out of date, and this is what I saw when I tried to `pip install ssl --upgrade`

`Collecting ssl
  Using cached ssl-1.16.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/xl/nl55_c357zd2gqs09wfwytvh0000gn/T/pip-build-tn97bV/ssl/setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        + "or earlier.")
    ValueError: This extension should not be used with Python 2.6 or later (already built in), and has not been tested with Python 2.3.4 or earlier.`

Comment: [Updating openssl in python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18752409), [How to use macport to install software?](http://superuser.com/q/377727), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), etc...

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue. Try replacing with ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1.

Also make sure your SSL version is >= 1.0.1  .

It worked for me .

Comment: I have a same problem but I already have openSSL 1.1.1 version, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343740/python-tls-version-matching how cna I solve my problem with your method?

Answer (score 0):

I was using python2.7.10. I changed my env to python2.7.13 which uses latest version of ssl which resolved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: It's not working and not at all recommended to use python 2.7.x so it's better to upgrade the python version to latest and try using the TLSv1_1/TLSv1_2.