# python 2.7.10 ssl missing TLSv1.1 on OS X

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

I need to connect to a server that only accepts TLS 1.1 and above.

I'm using the following code to test my SSL version:

```
>>> import requests
>>> print requests.get('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check').text
```

The relevant part of the response is `{"tls_version": "TLS 1.0"}`.

In digging into this, it seems that my version of the python ssl library doesn't support a higher version of TLS:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl._PROTOCOL_NAMES
{0: 'PROTOCOL_SSLv2',
 1: 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3',
 2: 'PROTOCOL_SSLv23',
 3: 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1'}
```

What can I do to get access to TLSv1.1 in python? I'm currently running `OS X 10.10.5`, `python 2.7.10`, and `OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015`. I've read that installing openssl and python through homebrew might solve my issue, but I'm wary of installing homebrewed python. I've done that in the past and remember having a lot of problems with it.

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000763/ssl-library-on-python-2-7-10-does-not-contain-protocol-tlsv1-2-and-upgrading-ssl) seems to be the same, but it is unanswered at the moment.

Comment: ***`OpenSSL 0.9.8`*** - yep, OpenSSL 0.9.8 is downlevel, it only supports TLS 1.0, and it lacks nearly all the EC goodies. You need an updated OpenSSL, and an updated Python. Macports is usually a good choice.

Comment: [Updating openssl in python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18752409), [How to use macport to install software?](http://superuser.com/q/377727), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), etc...

Comment: @jww okay, I was scared of homebrewed python but so far things are going well. Thanks :)