# How to use `curl` in old OSX?

Tags: macos, curl, osx-leopard

I have an old Mac mini 2006 with the following characteristics:

```
  System Version: Mac OS X 10.5.8 (9L31a)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 9.8.0
  Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
```

on which I need to install some tools.

First of all note that I cannot use the browser because out of date and there are no software updates available from the Menu.

I need to install an old version of openCV and NodeJS tools such as `nvm` `npm` `nodeExpress` and few others.

However `wget` is not recognized as command and `curl` returns an error suggesting to use `curl --insecure`.

The command `curl --insecure` returns the error

```
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

While for openCV I could download the source code in another computer and then copy it there, I cannot think of any workaround for installing the other tools (directly or with `brew` since the installation is done with `curl`).

So my question is: how to make `curl` work on this OSX version or at least how to update it?

**EDIT1**: Trying to install homebrew I first downloaded the command, copied the file in the minimac and try to execute it. The error is:

```
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
This installation may not succeed.
After installation, you will encounter build failures and other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's
GitHub, Discourse, Twitter or IRC. As you are running this old version,
you are responsible for resolving any issues you experience.

==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
/usr/bin/tar: Child returned status 1
/usr/bin/tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
Failed during: /bin/bash -o pipefail -c '/usr/bin/curl -fsSLk https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | /usr/bin/tar xz -m --strip 1'
```

Comment: Can you use an “http” URL instead of “https”?

Comment: trying to download opencv with `curl http://github.com/opencv/archive/2.4.13.6.zip
` does not doing anything while trying to install brew result in the same error.

Comment: Looks like that just redirects to the https URL, so it won't help. Can you download the file on another computer and transfer it locally?

Comment: see edit1. At this point maybe the only option is find an update

Comment: install VMWare on it and install a Ubuntu minimal server edition (need about 150MB ram) on the VM and use curl there.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but you might be able to run a web proxy that'd accept old-version TLS (https) connections (like v10.5's `curl` knows how to do) and then make newer-version TLS connections out to the web server. See the question [Can I use Squid to upgrade client TLS connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398484/can-i-use-squid-to-upgrade-client-tls-connections) for info on how to configure squid's settings to do this. [Squidman](http://squidman.net/squidman/index.html) is downloadable with plain http, and includes a prebuilt copy of squid (along with a GUI setup/wrapper application). Squidman v3.1 was the last to support OS X v10.5, and I don't know what versions of TLS that'll support.

In OS X, there are sort of two different ways to configure client software to use a proxy. For GUI apps (browsers, etc), you make the relevant settings in System Preferences -> Network pane -> select the relevant service/interface -> Advanced button -> Proxy tab. For CLI tools like `curl`, you can generally either pass explicit options to them (probably won't work here), or set environment variables e.g. `export HTTPS_PROXY=https://127.0.0.1:8080`.

If you can upgrade OS X to v10.6, the builtin version of `curl` is still pretty limited, but you'll be able to run newer version of Squidman (though not necessarily the latest -- it supports v10.6, but only 64-bit Intel CPUs). Apple apparently [still sells OS X v10.6 on DVD through their online store](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard). Note that they also list newer versions, but all they get you is a download code to use in the App Store... which wasn't added until v10.6.6.

Comment: I tried to use an installation disc of Snow Leopard that I had. From the operating system when before even clicking on the `Install Mac OSX` file of the disc drive it tells me `Snow Leopard cannot be installed on this Mac`

Comment: Does your Mac Mini have a PowerPC CPU? If so, they dropped support for those in 10.6, so 10.5.8 is the latest available OS.