# How to support TLS 1.1, 1.2 for Python (2.7)

Tags: python, tls1.2

I have developed an application in Python 2.7. But it only supports **PROTOCOL_TLSv1**. I have to somehow make it compatible with **PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1** and **PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2**. I can't find any library or trick to do so. Is it necessary to upgrade the Python version?

Kindly guide me or help me find the better solution.
Isn't there any out of the way solution?

Comment: Which SSL library are you using?

Comment: @SimonFraser I am sorry, how do I check it? I don't understand your question.

Comment: What are you doing to get TLSv1 support? Did you install the "pyopenssl" module, have `import ssl` in your code, or something else?

Comment: @SimonFraser Well I have not used `import ssl` explicitly or installed "pyopenssl". For communication (request/response) I am using `requests 2.9.1` library

Comment: I think this is the answer you're after, then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29155638/3527520, with the `SSLContext` and the link to the requests documentation at the bottom for how to use it

Comment: @SimonFraser does this means that I have to upgrade my python version? Isn't there any out of the way solution?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed I'm afraid you'll have to upgrade your python version. Not that it is a bad thing. Upgrading to Python 2.7.9 or later should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

libopenssl1 and python 2.7.9 provided you can force ssl.SSLContext like :

```
import ssl, urllib2
ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
```