# TLS 1.2 in Python 2.7.14

Tags: python, tls1.2

Force `TLS 1.2` in `Python 2.7.14`

Hi I need to update my python code (version 2.7.14) which uses `urllib2.open` to force it to use `TLS1.2`
So far I have tried 
[Sending TLS 1.2 request in Python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153271/sending-tls-1-2-request-in-python-2-6)

But I get `AttributeError("'module' object has no attribute 'SSLContext'",)`

```
 ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
 response = urllib2.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
```

The options I have SSLContext are

```
PROTOCOL_TLSv1
PROTOCOL_SSLv23
PROTOCOL_SSLv2
PROTOCOL_SSLv3
```

`PROTOCOL_TLSv2` is not available

Comment: Friendly warning: Python 2.7 is EOL in 8 months. https://pythonclock.org/ Please consider upgrading asap.

Comment: I was really hesitant to go from 2 to 3 for a long time... but for a while now it's been a necessary transition. Particularly with the evolving SSL situation. Without more context on your project, we can't offer more useful guidance, but at this point it's almost certainly in your best interest to put in whatever time it takes to update to 3.x.

Comment: Hi I would update to 3x, but we have a number of other scripts developed with v2.7, hence will be much effort to upgrade all. But anyway, how would v3x help with the TLS 1.2 issue?