# How can I provide protocol TLS 1.2 support to connect to a SQL Server database in python 2.7 via ODBC?

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, tls1.2

How can I provide protocol TLS 1.2 support to connect to a SQL Server database in Python 2.7? Connection is carried out through pyodbc module...

Comment: Questions (and hints towards the answer):  What ODBC driver are you using? What version of SQL Server are you using? It looks like you are using Python 2.7.x - that should support TLS 1.2, so you should be good there. Have you disabled TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1. Finally, have you reviewed this Stack Overflow's question and answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153271/sending-tls-1-2-request-in-python-2-6